# Delete the latest message of the bot in dms

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a command where the bot sends a message to a specific user trough private messages. Now I want that I can delete the last message of the bot in DMs when there is like an error or something.

What I come up with is this:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'dmdelete',
    aliases: ['dmerase'],
    description: 'Deletes last DM Bot Message.',
    usage: '<user>',
    staff: true,
    execute(message, args) {
            const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first().id
            const User = client.users.fetch(mentionedMember)
            try {
                    if (!mentionedMember) {
                            return respond('', 'Bitte erwähne einen Nutzer.', message.channel)
                    }
                    User.dmChannel.messages.fetch( {limit: 1} )
                    .then(messages => {
                        let lastMessage = messages.first();
                        if (!lastMessage.author.bot) return;
                        lastMessage.delete()

                    });

            } catch (error) {
                    console.error('an error has occured', error);
            }
    }
}
```

The error that I'm getting now is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined
```

And yes, I have direct messages with the bot.

Anyone knows what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors. First, [`users.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) and [`dmChannel.messages.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) both return a promise, so you'll need for them to be resolved.

In your code above, `User` is a *pending Promise* that has no `dmChannel` property. As it has no `dmChannel` prop (i.e. it's `undefined`), you can't read its `messages` property and you will receive `TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined`.

After you fixed these problems with `fetch`, there could be another error with the `dmChannel`. Sometimes (or most of the times?), `user.dmChannel` returns `null`. To avoid this, you can create a DM channel first using the [`createDM()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createDM) method. It also returns a promise, so you will need to resolve it first :)

Check out the working code below:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'dmdelete',
  aliases: ['dmerase'],
  description: 'Deletes last DM Bot Message.',
  usage: '<user>',
  staff: true,
  async execute(message, args) {
    const mentionedUser = message.mentions.users.first();

    if (!mentionedUser)
      return respond('', 'Bitte erwähne einen Nutzer.', message.channel);

    const user = await client.users.fetch(mentionedUser.id);
    const dmChannel = user.dmChannel || (await user.createDM());

    try {
      const messages = await dmChannel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 });
      let lastMessage = messages.first();
      if (!lastMessage.author.bot) return;
      lastMessage.delete();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('an error has occured', error);
    }
  },
};
```